# catching button clicks in javascript without server interaction

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got a sign up form that requires the user to enter their email and password, both are in two separate text boxes. I want to provide a button that the user can click so that the password (which is masked) will appear in a popup when the user clicks the button.

Currently my JavaScript code for this is as follows:

```
    function toggleShowPassword() {       
        var button = $get('PASSWORD_TEXTBOX_ID');
        var password;
        if (button)
        {
            password = button.value;
            alert(password);
            button.value = password;  
        } 
   }
```

The problem is that every time the user clicks the button, the password is cleared in both Firefox and IE. I want them to be able to see their password in clear text to verify without having to retype their password.

My questions are:

1. Why does the password field keep getting reset with each button click?
2. How can I make it so the password field is NOT cleared once the user has seen his/her password in clear text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick example up of a working version:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function toggleShowPassword() {       
                var textBox = $('PasswordText');
                if (textBox)
                {
                    alert(textBox.value);  
                } 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="password" id="PasswordText" /><input type="button" onclick="toggleShowPassword();" value="Show Password" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The key is that the input is of type button and not submit.  I used the [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) library for retrieving the element by ID.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the browser has some issue with the script attempting to set the value of a password field:

```
button.value = password;
```

This line of code has no real purpose. `password.value` is not affected in the previous lines where you are reading the value and using it in the `alert()`.

This should be a simpler version of your code:

```
function toggleShowPassword() {       
    var button = $get('PASSWORD_TEXTBOX_ID');
    if (button)
    {
        alert(button.value);
    }
```

}

edit: actually I just did a quick test, and Firefox has no problem setting the password field's value with code such as `button.value = "blah"`. So it doesn't seem like this would be the case ... I would check if your ASP.NET code is causing a postback as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds that you're doing a request to the server on each click, the password box being reset in each page load is typical behavior of the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say you were using ASP.NET, but...

By design, ASP.NET clears during postback the value of TextBox controls whose Mode is Password.  I work around this in a subclass with the following code:

```
// If the TextMode is "password", the Text property won't work
if ( TextMode == System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode.Password )
    Attributes[ "value" ] = stringValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the button to submit the form, then be sure it has type 'button' rather than 'submit'.  For example, you might do something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Show My Password" onclick="toggleShowPassword()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="toggleShowPassword();">
```

You need to use "button" rather than "submit" to prevent your form from posting.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do `button.value = password;` since reading the value does not change it. I'm not sure why it's being cleared, maybe JavaScript does not allow password field values to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

hah!

the answer if here:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1067527/1548528.aspx

I figured out the solution... the fix was simple change

```
  OnClientClick="myOnClick()"
```

to

```
  OnClientClick="return myOnClick()"
```

Here's the fully corrected code...

function myOnClick() {
            //perform some other actions...
            return false;
        }
    
    Untitled Page